# Connect Motorola DS3578 batch scanner to web service

Tags: web-development

I'm looking for a tool to deliver barcodes, scanned in batch mode, using a Motorola DS3578 scanner, to a website, using a web service.

As I'm developing the web application, I can make the web service do basically whatever I want, so it's really the tool I'm looking for.

Preferably this is a very simple tool, as it will need to be installed, unattended, on every PC with this scanner connected to it. These PC's will run Windows OS, but can have various operating system languages running.

The moment the scanner is inserted back into its craddle, the tool should automatically pick up the barcodes, and transmit them to the webservice, preferably without any user interface interfering.

Comment: A barcode scanner is usually just a keyboard, which means you can create a basic web interface and have some Javascript code do whatever you want. And it'll be cross-platform.

Comment: André, this is true, but you can also use a barcode scanner in "batch" mode. This means you'll gather several hundreds of barcodes, and then "push them through" when the scanner is finally placed in its craddle. In that case you need a "tool" to communicate with your website (through a webservice)

Comment: When used in batch mode, does it need a special driver or does it still appear as a keyboard ? If it's still detected as a keyboard then I'd still suggest using JS.

Comment: No, in that case it is accessed through an API. The website is not even active at that moment